# Java Cannot cast reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer to EntityClass

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, project-reactor

Here I try to upgrade my spring-data-redis `RedisTemplate` using reactive-redis `ReactiveRedisTemplate` which is returning Publisher. In this case, I want to change the method `findCache` to `Mono`. The problem is old `findCache` function that is using spring-data-redis is accepting generic data, like this:

```
@Autowired
ReactiveRedisTemplate redisTemplate;

public <T> T findCache(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    Object content = this.redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);

    if (content != null) {
      return clazz.cast(content);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

of course I will get the error

```
Cannot cast reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer to Person
```

then, since I want to get it to work reactively I update this code to return publisher, like this:

```
if (content != null) {
      return ((Mono) content).flatMap(o -> clazz.cast(o));
    }
```

but it also won't work since my `findCache` accepts generic.
What do I need to do, please help.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to specify `ReactiveRedisTemplate` parameters. But if you can't, you should change your content type to `Mono<Object>`. Something like this:

```
public <T> Mono<T> findCache(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Mono<Object> contentMono = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
    return contentMono.map(clazz::cast);
}
```

And if cache doesn't contain value for given key, it returns empty Mono, not null.

Comment: it is still not working Mr. Alex, i got `reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap cannot be cast to Person`, any other guess that may help?

Comment: How do you set value to the cache? You should set Person object, not Mono<Person>